# Друзья, помогите проверить ошибки в данном тексте

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, стилистика

Не ищите причины, не говорите, что нет  мест, где можно заниматься, если хочешь, то найдёшь и не обязательно заниматься в зале, можно и на улице,  главное никому не мешать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Не ищите причины, не говорите, что нет мест, где можно заниматься (если хочешь, то найдёшь). И не обязательно заниматься в зале, можно и на улице, главное — никому не мешать.**

Придаточное условное оформлено в виде **вставной  конструкции с использованием скобок,** так как другие варианты (тире, двоеточие) перед подчинительным союзом в правилах не прописаны, а **предложение явно вставочного характера** (с измененной грамматикой) и должно выделяться из основного текста как добавочное замечание.

Разбивка на два предложения также желательна (и по смыслу, и по интонации), но их связывает **присоединительный** союз И.

Comment: Благодарю........

Answer (score 3):

Согласен с Jasmin, что предложение "если хочешь, то найдешь" должно быть отделено от других. Наряду со скобками, характерными для письменной речи, могу предложить вариант, который, на мой взгляд, ближе к разговорному:

**Не ищите причины, не говорите, что нет мест, где можно заниматься. Если хочешь, то найдёшь. И не обязательно заниматься в зале, можно и на улице, главное — никому не мешать.**

Comment: М_Г, тоже благодарю... Если честно, я склонялся, больше к вашему варианту... Но и ответ Jasmin, вполне подходит.... Я не силен в грамматике,  но так как данное предложение было выдрано из контекста и тем более не мной (попросили проверить ошибки). Однозначного ответа, думаю, не может быть...

Comment: Почти всегда есть несколько правильных вариантов. Выбор  за автором.

Comment: Ну вот и я об этом...

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь две основные мысли,  поэтому я не стала делить текст на три предложения. Даже в устной речи должна быть обозначена более тесная связь между предложениями 1 и 2 (меньшей паузой), так как предложение 2 по смыслу поясняет предложение 1.

Comment: @Jasmin Здесь две основные мысли — в этом нет сомнения. Но это на одной чаше весов. А на другой — нежелательность скобок при передаче разговорной речи. Не знаю, что весомее. Думаю, оба варианта имеют право на существование.

Comment: Разве скобки  имеют стилевую принадлежность? Тематика у них разнообразная,  в частности они могут использоваться  для обособления  вставных конструкций, представляющих собой попутные авторские замечания (как раз наша тема). У Розенталя много примеров, где скобки применяются  в разговорной речи персонажей, например: "он купил мне серьги, тихонько от меня (а я всё узнала), и радовался, как ребёнок" (Дост.).